# Django displaying model on web page

Tags: python, html, django, model-view-controller

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I'm creating a web store using Django/HTML/Foundations and I can't get the products that are in the database to display on the web page. I know they're in the database because when i go to admin page, they show up.

Here's the HTML piece:

```
{% for products in Product %}
<div class="column">
  <h5>Title: {{products.product_name}}</h5>
  <h5>Type: {{products.product_type}}</h5>
  <h5>Price: {{products.sales_price}}</h5>
  <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/550x550">
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Here's the Model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sales_price = models.CharField(max_length=10)g

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name + " " + self.product_type + " " + self.sales_price
```

The only thing in my views.py for products page is: (might be where my problem lies)

```
def products(request):
    return render(request,"products.html")
```

I'm new to django and python. Could someone please explain what's happening? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your view needs to provide the `products` information to the template by using the `context` argument. [See the documentation for render()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render).

views.py:

```
def products(request):
    context = {'products':Product.objects.all()}
    return render(request,"products.html",context)
```

products.html:

```
{% for product in products %}
<div class="column">
     <h5>Title: {{product.product_name}}</h5>
     <h5>Type: {{product.product_type}}</h5>
     <h5>Price: {{product.sales_price}}</h5>
     <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/550x550">
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You could probably use a ListView, wich is a [generic view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) and your template to archieve the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your for loop from

```
{% for products in Product %}
```

to

```
{% for product in products %}
```

because you want to display a single product from the group of products each time you process through the loop.

Comment: yeah I tried changing it to that, no change. I'm a little new to python, but the way I wrote it is for (some made up variable) in (model name). Then to access the variables in the model, it's products.variableName. Did I do that right? In the adjustment here, it's flipped (model first then some created variable). No difference in how it's working though.